# PyInstaller doesn't import Queue

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm trying to compile some script with twisted and Queue.

```
pyinstaller sample.py --onefile
```

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-#
from twisted import *
import queue as Queue
a = Queue.Queue()
```

Unfortunately, produced file fails with `ImportError: No module named queue`.

Comment: I've also tried: pyinstaller sample.py --onefile --hidden-import queue but stiill no luck. My Python is 2.x

Comment: It might be better if you add more detail. It helps others like me in not asking the same question again if we have the same issue.(https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/How-to-Report-Bugs). Cheers!

Comment: Please refer to https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1939#issuecomment-213976155

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia asked to add this [link](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1939#issuecomment-213165667) also. So I did.

Comment: If you are using windows, the problem might be: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1935

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get success by use this naming. I use Python 2.7

```
import Queue
queue = Queue.Queue()
```

and with pyinstaller pass this argument :

```
--hidden-import=Queue
```

and it works.

Answer (score 8):

I don't think this is a PyInstaller or Twisted related issue at all. The `Queue` module is part of the standard library, and the issue is how you're naming it. In Python 2, it's `Queue` with a capital letter, but in Python 3, it's renamed `queue` to follow the more standard naming convention where modules have lowercase names.

Your script seems like it's a port of Python 2 code to Python 3 (thus the `as Queue` part of the `import`), but you're running it with Python 2 still. That may fail in other more subtle ways than just the `Queue` import being wrong (e.g. its Unicode handling may be all wrong).

Comment: Even removing that import the error persists, I am guessing it's because of import Queue in twisted. This should provide more details http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12037835

Comment: Hmm, if that edit's error message is correct, you're not able to import `Queue` with a capital `Q` either. In that case I have no idea what's going on. I do see a bug filed on PyInstaller (perhaps by you one one of the other users here?): https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1939

Comment: @Blckknght It's Twisted who imports queue. I've added "import queue" to main file hoping that PyInstaller could hook that import. But it didn't.

Answer (score 7):

```
pip install twisted --upgrade
```

fixed everything.

**update**

also don't forget to use  **--hidden-import=queue** in cmdline.

Comment: It still doesn't work for me. Does it work without onefile for you?

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia downvoting this because it did not work for you is not the proper use of downvoting. This is the solution that pmus found for their own question. So this answer is valid in this case. If you find another solution for this exact situation, then you can post it and explain. Or if you think the downvote is valid because this solution is wrong or bad, then explain so.

Comment: @pmus Please provide details to the twisted version you are using after upgrade and before. Also, since it likely that issue can specific to OS one is using. Not mentioning that is also not helpful to others like me who are having the same issue. Thanks!

Comment: Uninstall/install/reinstall how to fix `LSB` errors ? @pmus

Comment: @pmus what version of python are you using?

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia I am using Python 2.7.11 x32 Windows version. Added --hidden-import=queue to my cmdline:

pyinstaller --clean -F -c --hidden-import=queue main.py

And updated twisted, and voila! It works now.

Comment: @pmus The correct way to make this work https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1939#issuecomment-213165667. Why didn't you mention the hidden-import before!! I can't comprehend why updating twisted makes it work. Please don't provide incorrect(incomplete) answers to your own questions.

Comment: @pmus If possible please go through the link, and update your answer to mention all steps you followed. Right now, it is incorrect. The issue is due to pyinstaller not twisted.

Comment: I bet that every issue of compiling **working python code** with PyInstaller is issue by PyInstaller. I provided a working fix, don't care if it's correct while it works.

Remember that "Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission" - that's written in Python documentation.

Comment: @pmus according to you, it works without hidden import?

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia No, it still requires hidden-import to get a working exe.

And as I said before, adding hidden-import and updating twisted solved the problem.

Comment: @pmus So, then add it in the answer. It misguides anyone searching for it.  He/she will think updating twisted makes it work. The reason why adding `hidden-imports` works can be found at the link before. :)

Comment: @Abishek Bhatia, press F5 and then for 10 seconds read line by line, and you'll soon get it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110687/discussion-between-pmus-and-abhishek-bhatia).

Comment: @pmus thanks, it is complete now. I would an answer it myself but it is someone else who solved the issue (, referring to github link).

Answer (score 1):

On windows using Python 2.7, pyinstaller up to 3.2 can be confused by the queue and Queue modules having similar names. https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1935

This is fixed on the trunk of pyinstaller. I had to install pyinstaller from source to work around the bug.

```
git clone https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller
cd pyinstaller
python setup.py install
```